# What does -webkit-text-size-adjust do?

Tags: android, ios, css, webkit

I am trying to understand the use of `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;`.

Adding/Removing that doesn't affect my font sizes on android (chrome) or iOS (safari and chrome). So what's the use?

Comment: Removing does not change anything, because `none` is default value.

Comment: I thought `auto` was default.

Comment: This question isn't about opinion, or emotional value - but rather a clear and straight forward "I tried xyz and it didn't seem to have an affect, so help me community to understand xyz." - should be re-opened.

Answer (score 21):

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust
```

It specifies that if you(author) want's to resize the text when the browser page is zoomed. Most of the times it is better to set it to `auto` or `100%` as the web browser will take care of how resizing of text is to be done.

Note : Mozilla devlopers page says its a [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-size-adjust)

This [article](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/iphone-text-resizing/) will help you more.

Interesting note : Developers using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) may be interested to know that Bootstrap uses `‑webkit‑text‑size‑adjust: 100%` out of the box : [Source Link](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/iphone-text-resizing/#fnref:bootstrap)

**Edit**

Chrome on android phones uses [font boosting](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2012-May/020819.html), so `-webkit-text-size-adjust` is ***being ignored*** no matter what value you set. You can disable font boosting it by setting `max-height` to something large(`100000px` or so) see this [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=FontBoosting).

Comment: just read the bootstrap note. but honestly, I think my question is still unanswered I think. Now i learnt that using `none` is bad for desktop browsers, but how is it exactly affecting mobile browsers ? I just don't see any changes on setting the property to `none`.

Comment: what is the browser you are using?

Comment: safari+chrome on iOS 6 (ipad) and chrome on android 4.2 (nexus)

Answer (score 9):

The `-webkit-text-size-adjust` is an [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-size-adjust) specifies a size adjustment for displaying text content in Safari on iPhone. It takes 3 type of value:

- none: The text size is not adjusted.
- auto(default): The text size is automatically adjusted for Safari on iPhone.
- The size in percentage at which to display text in Safari on iPhone.

Only some mobile browsers do support this CSS property beside iOS. You can check the compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-size-adjust#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be any published specification of `-webkit-text-size-adjust`, but there is e.g. an informal [description](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-text-size-adjust), which says that it works in Safari on iPhone.

According to [CSS Mobile Text Size Adjustment Module Level](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-size-adjust/#text-size-adjust) (Editor’s Draft), `auto` is the initial value, so `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none` would have an effect only when it overrides a setting that sets the property to a different value. Presumably  `-webkit-text-size-adjust` works mostly the same way as the planned `text-size-adjust` property.