# Long h1 increases font size of all statically-positioned text in mobile browsers

Tags: android, html

I've found that in the Chrome and Firefox mobile browsers, an h1 over a certain length increases the font size of all statically-positioned text on the page but not absolutely-positioned text.  The length of the h1 required to trigger the problem seems to depend on the browser and (probably) the device.

For example, on a Nexus 4 using Chrome or Firefox, the h1 text and statically-positioned div text from the following code renders too large while the absolutely-positioned div text renders in normal size.  Removing 2 characters of text from the h1 tag causes all text to render in normal size in Chrome.  Removing 2 more characters causes all text to render in normal size in Firefox.

```
    <html>
    <body style="margin: 0;">
    <h1 style="font-size: 1em;">h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1 h1</h1>
    <div style="font-size: 1em;">div</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 1em;">absolute</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to control it?

Comment: Got it! The big break was the edit in the main answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861093/what-does-webkit-text-size-adjust-do

"Chrome on android phones uses font boosting, so -webkit-text-size-adjust is being ignored no matter what value you set. You can disable font boosting it by setting max-height to something large(100000px or so) see this bug."

That's it in a nutshell. My example code can be "fixed" by setting h1,div {max-height: 100000px;}.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried experimenting with the viewport meta? This meta allows the mobile browser to determine the size of certain elements based on your size specifications.

This is how you apply it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: That viewport setting causes the text from my example code to appear in the larger size consistently, but if I apply that to my site everything is much too large and goes off the page on a mobile browser. I've been playing with it a lot but my site has a liquid design and it looks best without viewport constraints.  I've added some clarification to my original post.

Comment: Is there a viewport setting that will make the font sizes consistent without affecting a site's layout in other ways?

Comment: I tried what o showed here and still can't understand the poblem http://jsfiddle.net/dkekR/ - Have you tried using a CSS reset, it can probably be something about the native browser CSS interfering?

Comment: The problem does not seem to manifest inside a jsfiddle compartment.  Can you dump the test code onto a page and open it in mobile Chrome or mobile Firefox?  I tried using the Meyer CSS reset and discovered that adding style="margin: 0;" to the body tag allows me to enter a few more characters in the h1 tag before the problem manifests.  I've updated my original post.

Comment: Have you tried to play with the em's? It seems the problem has to do with that, since it is the only thing interfering with the native browser font-size. You should even try checking your browser viewing definitions, since it can be a code interpretation issue.

Comment: The problem exists even if the font-size declarations are entirely removed.  I included them to show that the problem exists even if the font-size is defined.  I see this problem on 4 browser instances with default configs (Chrome and Firefox on 2 Android devices) so I don't think it's a config issue.  Have you tried it outside of jsfiddle?