# Some Text content in the Website appears bigger on the mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Is there a way for the text size to be reduced automatically when the website is viewed from a mobile device? The content is perfect and everything else, and browser-wise it works great, but now mobile is the issue. Should I make a completely different website for mobile devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to prevent that

```
body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}
```

More info here:
[What does -webkit-text-size-adjust do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861093/what-does-webkit-text-size-adjust-do)

Answer (score 2):

Use the viewport `<meta>` tag in your `<head>`. Set up like below to handle responsiveness regardless of what viewport/device you're using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

See [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/) for more info.