# Turn Off Chrome's Autosizing Text in Emulator Mode

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome (v40) has an emulator "feature" [described thus](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode):

- Autosizes (boosts) text for pages without a defined viewport.

However, I have a page (with a defined viewport) on which it's scaling my font size. This makes all the font sizes completely different than on the actual device (several versions of iOS, which isn't scaling them).

[image]

Several search results show there have been several variations on how to change this setting (e.g. `DevTools -> Settings -> Override tab` and `DevTools -> Emulation -> Screen`--neither of which exist as of v40). I can't currently find any way to turn this feature off.

Due to design, my viewport is defined as (I need it to not scale and start zoomed out):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000" />
```

So is there some checkbox or chrome://flags setting I can change to turn this off or override it?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround, found on a [slightly related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15861196/3617), is to set a max-height on the element being scaled to something very large (e.g. 100000px).

So, for testing purposes, I can add this to the CSS and get around this issue:

```
* { max-height: 100000px; }
```

I'd still like a setting somewhere to explicitly turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

Click the drawer console icon (or hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>) in the devtools and go to Emulation tab.

Then flick off the "Emulate Mobile" checkbox. It does autosizing and a few other things.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it also disables the meta viewport support which prevents it from displaying the page zoomed out. Kind of a circular problem. The best answer is probably to not have a design that creates this problem.